# Simple Navigation bar not working: only blank div showing up

Tags: html, css, uinavigationbar

So, I made a really cool website. Then, in a separate file, I made a really cool navigation bar. However, when I put them together, the navigation bar is gone. The background of the very first div called "list" should be filled and should bigger, however, it is not. Hopefully, someone can help me to have the navigation bar and site on the same page. Thanks!

```css
        
.list {
  background-color: #666;
    color: #111111;
    height: 105px;
    width: 100%;
}

.list a {
    
  margin-top: 20px;  
  float: right;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;   
    
}

.list a:hover {
  background-color: #70b5ff;
  color: #111111;
}

.list a.on {
background-color: #81ff7c;
  color: #005604; 
}

.imagefornav {
 
    width: 160px;
    height: 100px;
    
}



body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    line-height: 35px;  
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #797a7c;
}

.title {
      letter-spacing: 5px;
    color: #1d3863; 
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: underline overline;
    font-size: 35px;
      line-height: 75px;
    margin-top: 13%;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 1.00;
    padding-right: 370px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 370px;
    animation: Fadein 2s ease-in;
}

@keyframes Fadein {
    
 from {
     opacity: 0;
    }
    
    to {
        opacity: 0.80;
    }
    
}

.imgc1, #imgc2, #imgc3, #imgc4 {
 position: relative;
     opacity: 0.80;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}


.imgc1 {
    
    background-image: url("http://pluspng.com/img-png/ocean-background-png-hd-superior-ocean-background-wallpapers-widescreen-for-desktop-2560.jpg");
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: -16px;
    
}

.border1 {
 
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: #111;
 font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    
}


#imgc2 {
     background-image: url("https://wallpaperstream.com/wallpapers/full/desert-sand/Algodones-Dunes-Desert-Sand-HD-Wallpaper.jpg");
    height: 600px;
    background-position: center right;

}

#Imgtxt1 {
    font-size: 41px;
    line-height: 100px; 
    color: #111111;
    padding-top: 100px;

    
}



#imgc3 {
     background-image: url("http://pluspng.com/img-png/ocean-background-png-hd-superior-ocean-background-wallpapers-widescreen-for-desktop-2560.jpg");
    height: 650px;
   
}

#section1 {
 text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 70px;
    font-size: 19px;
     
   
}

#section2 {
 text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 70px;
    background-color: #666;
        color: #f4f4f4;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0px;

    
    
}

#section3 {
 height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    
    
}

.invis {
 visibility: hidden;   
}

#BF {
   
    font-size: 15px;
    animation: Comein 200s ease-in;
   padding-left: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes Comein {
    
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     padding-left: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    6% {
        opacity: 0;
     padding-left: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    7% {
     
     opacity: 1;   
        padding-left: 600px;
         visibility: visible;
    }
    
    100% {
       
        padding-left: 601px;
        opacity: 1;   
    }
    
    
}

#ranger {
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#borderabout {
    background-color: #666;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 25px;
    opacity: 0.70;
}

#borderourgoal {
      font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 70px;
}

#ourgoal {
    
    letter-spacing: 10px;
}

#you {
    
    font-size: 60px;
    
}

#about {
 
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    
}


#border3 {
 
    background-color: #1be2e5;
    opacity: 0.60;
    height: 650px;
    color: #111111;
    
    
}

#opacityforborder3 {
 
  
  padding-top: 200px;
    font-size: 30px;
    
}

#imgtxt2 {
    
  height: 100%;
    
}
   

.button1 {
    
    border-radius: 15px;
     margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 605px;
    border: none;
     background-color: #666;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
    
}

.button1:hover {
 
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #666;
     border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1.5px;
    border-color: #666;
    
}

#contacts {
    
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}



#button2 {
    
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 300px;
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
     background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ab/Gmail_Icon.svg/100px-Gmail_Icon.svg.png");
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    
    
}

#button2:hover {
    
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 285px;
     height: 140px;
     width: 140px;
     background: url("https://lh6.ggpht.com/8-N_qLXgV-eNDQINqTR-Pzu5Y8DuH0Xjz53zoWq_IcBNpcxDL_gK4uS_MvXH00yN6nd4=w140-rw");
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-top: 5px;
   
    
    
}

#Mygmail {
 
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 290px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 75%;
    
   
}

#dots {
    
 visibility: hidden;
    
}

#refs {
 
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    
}

#linktext {
 
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    
    
}

#link01 {
    
    margin-left: 300px;
    
}


#link1 {
 
    margin-left: 170px;
    
}

#link2 {
    
    margin-left: 60px;
    
}

#link3 {
    
    margin-left: 125px;
    
}

#link4 {
    
    margin-left: 50px;
    
}

a {
    
    color: #60d16b;
    
}



#imgc4 {
    
     background-color: #666;
    height: 300px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
   
}

#image1 {
    
    height: 265px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#byme {
    
 margin-left: 350px;
    font-size: 13px;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Resource Rangers</title>
    <link href="CSS for 4th project (1).css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<style>
</style>
<body>
    <div class="List">
        <a class="a1" href="about.asp">Lack of Water</a>
        <a href="about.asp">Waters Journey</a>
        <a href="contact.asp">How</a>
        <a href="news.asp">Why?</a>
        <a class="on" href="default.asp">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="imgc1"><br>
        <div class="title">
            <div class="border1">
                <h3 align="center"> Resource Rangers </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="section1">
        <div id="about">
            <h2> About </h2>
        </div>
        <section>
            <div id="borderabout">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse blandit tortor varius, suscipit
                    felis nec, consectetur est. Fusce at commodo velit. Aenean dictum ipsum est, ut congue ligula
                    condimentum et. Nullam cursus a purus id maximus. Sed ullamcorper erat neque, placerat pellentesque
                    lectus scelerisque sit amet. Fusce mi enim, bibendum gravida ex vel, dignissim aliquam dui. Etiam
                    porta augue non dignissim sagittis. Suspendisse at quam a felis hendrerit aliquam. Sed elementum
                    dapibus venenatis. Sed a neque ac tellus auctor dictum ac ut ante. Cras a lectus et nisl faucibus
                    venenatis. Pellentesque placerat dolor at dolor bibendum maximus. Nullam faucibus massa at enim
                    blandit ultrices. Nulla dapibus lacinia turpis eu aliquam. Morbi at fringilla tortor, eu eleifend
                    leo. <span id="ranger">Resource Ranger!</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

    <div id="imgc2">
        <div id="Imgtxt1">
            <div id="border2">
                <h1 align="center"> "When the Wells dry, we know the worth of water"
                    <span class="invis">.</span>
                    <div id="BF"> - Benjamin Franklin </div>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="section2">
        <section>
            <div id="ourgoal">
                <h2> Our Goal </h2>
            </div>
            <div id="borderourgoal">
                <p>
                    <span id="you">You</span> to be inspired to and help you get involved, for the benefit of our
                    community of , as well as the global community, and our planet.
                </p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div id="imgc3">
        <div id="Imgtxt2">
            <div id="border3">
                <div id="opacityforborder3">
                    <h1 align="center" class="moreinfo"> To find out more information </h1>
                    <button class="button1" onclick="location.href = 'default.asp';">Click Here</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="section3">
        <span id="contacts">
            <h2> Contacts </h2>
        </span>
        <div id="Mygmail">
            <h3> My Gmail
                <span id="dots">......................................................</span>More References
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="stuff1">
            <button id="button2" onclick="location.href = 'https://www.lipsum.com/feed/html';"></button>
            <span id="refs"> <span id="linktext">Here are some more links if you are looking to go more in depth into
                    water conservation! </span><br>
            <span id="link01"><a href="https://saveourwater.com">https://saveourwater.com</a></span><br>
            <span id="link1"> <a href="https://www.farnellfamily.com/cfarnell/why/default.html">https://www.farnellfamily.com/cfarnell/why/default.html</a></span><br>
            <span id="link2"> <a href="https://learn.eartheasy.com/guides/45-ways-to-conserve-water-in-the-home-and-yard/">https://learn.eartheasy.com/guides/45-ways-to-conserve-water-in-the-home-and-yard/</a></span><br>
            <span id="link3"> <a href="https://www.constellation.com/energy-101/water-conservation-tips0.html">https://www.constellation.com/energy-101/water-conservation-tips0.html</a></span><br>
            <span id="link4"> <a href="https://www.lipsum.com/feed/html">https://www.lipsum.com/feed/html</a></span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="imgc4">
        <div id="Imgtxt3">
            <div id="border4">
                <img id="image1" src="wix3.png">
                <span id="byme">By All rights reserved</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html you apply the class `List`.
however, in your CSS you call .list (lowercase l).

Change your HTML class to `list` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Edited the snippet. In the html use 'list' instead of 'List'. Also I have made, .list position as fixed.

```css
.list {
  background-color: #666;
    color: #111111;
    height: 105px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.list a {
    
  margin-top: 20px;  
  float: right;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;   
    
}

.list a:hover {
  background-color: #70b5ff;
  color: #111111;
}

.list a.on {
background-color: #81ff7c;
  color: #005604; 
}

.imagefornav {
 
    width: 160px;
    height: 100px;
    
}



body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    line-height: 35px;  
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #797a7c;
}

.title {
      letter-spacing: 5px;
    color: #1d3863; 
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: underline overline;
    font-size: 35px;
      line-height: 75px;
    margin-top: 13%;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 1.00;
    padding-right: 370px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 370px;
    animation: Fadein 2s ease-in;
}

@keyframes Fadein {
    
 from {
     opacity: 0;
    }
    
    to {
        opacity: 0.80;
    }
    
}

.imgc1, #imgc2, #imgc3, #imgc4 {
 position: relative;
     opacity: 0.80;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}


.imgc1 {
    
    background-image: url("http://pluspng.com/img-png/ocean-background-png-hd-superior-ocean-background-wallpapers-widescreen-for-desktop-2560.jpg");
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: -16px;
    
}

.border1 {
 
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: #111;
 font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    
}


#imgc2 {
     background-image: url("https://wallpaperstream.com/wallpapers/full/desert-sand/Algodones-Dunes-Desert-Sand-HD-Wallpaper.jpg");
    height: 600px;
    background-position: center right;

}

#Imgtxt1 {
    font-size: 41px;
    line-height: 100px; 
    color: #111111;
    padding-top: 100px;

    
}



#imgc3 {
     background-image: url("http://pluspng.com/img-png/ocean-background-png-hd-superior-ocean-background-wallpapers-widescreen-for-desktop-2560.jpg");
    height: 650px;
   
}

#section1 {
 text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 70px;
    font-size: 19px;
     
   
}

#section2 {
 text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 70px;
    background-color: #666;
        color: #f4f4f4;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0px;

    
    
}

#section3 {
 height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    
    
}

.invis {
 visibility: hidden;   
}

#BF {
   
    font-size: 15px;
    animation: Comein 200s ease-in;
   padding-left: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes Comein {
    
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     padding-left: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    6% {
        opacity: 0;
     padding-left: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    7% {
     
     opacity: 1;   
        padding-left: 600px;
         visibility: visible;
    }
    
    100% {
       
        padding-left: 601px;
        opacity: 1;   
    }
    
    
}

#ranger {
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#borderabout {
    background-color: #666;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 25px;
    opacity: 0.70;
}

#borderourgoal {
      font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 70px;
}

#ourgoal {
    
    letter-spacing: 10px;
}

#you {
    
    font-size: 60px;
    
}

#about {
 
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    
}


#border3 {
 
    background-color: #1be2e5;
    opacity: 0.60;
    height: 650px;
    color: #111111;
    
    
}

#opacityforborder3 {
 
  
  padding-top: 200px;
    font-size: 30px;
    
}

#imgtxt2 {
    
  height: 100%;
    
}
   

.button1 {
    
    border-radius: 15px;
     margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 605px;
    border: none;
     background-color: #666;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
    
}

.button1:hover {
 
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #666;
     border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1.5px;
    border-color: #666;
    
}

#contacts {
    
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}



#button2 {
    
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 300px;
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
     background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ab/Gmail_Icon.svg/100px-Gmail_Icon.svg.png");
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    
    
}

#button2:hover {
    
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 285px;
     height: 140px;
     width: 140px;
     background: url("https://lh6.ggpht.com/8-N_qLXgV-eNDQINqTR-Pzu5Y8DuH0Xjz53zoWq_IcBNpcxDL_gK4uS_MvXH00yN6nd4=w140-rw");
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-top: 5px;
   
    
    
}

#Mygmail {
 
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 290px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 75%;
    
   
}

#dots {
    
 visibility: hidden;
    
}

#refs {
 
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    
}

#linktext {
 
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    
    
}

#link01 {
    
    margin-left: 300px;
    
}


#link1 {
 
    margin-left: 170px;
    
}

#link2 {
    
    margin-left: 60px;
    
}

#link3 {
    
    margin-left: 125px;
    
}

#link4 {
    
    margin-left: 50px;
    
}

a {
    
    color: #60d16b;
    
}



#imgc4 {
    
     background-color: #666;
    height: 300px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
   
}

#image1 {
    
    height: 265px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#byme {
    
 margin-left: 350px;
    font-size: 13px;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   
    
    
    
<head>
 <title>Resource Rangers</title>
    <link href ="CSS for 4th project (1).css" rel ="stylesheet">
</head>
    
    
    <style>

    </style>

    
    
<body>
    
    
    
 <div class="list">
  <a class= "a1" href="about.asp">Lack of Water</a>
  <a href="about.asp">Waters Journey</a>
        <a href="contact.asp">How</a>
        <a href="news.asp">Why?</a>
        <a class= "on" href="default.asp">Home</a>
</div>
    <div class= "imgc1">

<br>
    
    
    <div class= "title">
        <div class= "border1">
            <h3 align="center"> Resource Rangers </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
    <div id= "section1">
        <div id= "about">
        <h2> About </h2>
            </div>
        <section>
        <div id= "borderabout">
        <p> 
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse blandit tortor varius, suscipit felis nec, consectetur est. Fusce at commodo velit. Aenean dictum ipsum est, ut congue ligula condimentum et. Nullam cursus a purus id maximus. Sed ullamcorper erat neque, placerat pellentesque lectus scelerisque sit amet. Fusce mi enim, bibendum gravida ex vel, dignissim aliquam dui. Etiam porta augue non dignissim sagittis. Suspendisse at quam a felis hendrerit aliquam. Sed elementum dapibus venenatis. Sed a neque ac tellus auctor dictum ac ut ante. Cras a lectus et nisl faucibus venenatis. Pellentesque placerat dolor at dolor bibendum maximus. Nullam faucibus massa at enim blandit ultrices. Nulla dapibus lacinia turpis eu aliquam. Morbi at fringilla tortor, eu eleifend leo. <span id= "ranger">Resource Ranger!</span>

        </p>
        </div> 
            </section> 
         </div>
    
<div id= "imgc2">
    <div id="Imgtxt1">
        <div id= "border2">
            <h1 align="center"> "When the Wells dry, we know the worth of water"       
                <span class= "invis">.</span> <div id= "BF"> - Benjamin Franklin </div> </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
    
    
    <div id= "section2">
      <section>
          <div id= "ourgoal">
        <h2> Our Goal </h2>
          </div>
          <div id= "borderourgoal">
          <p> 
               <span id= "you">You</span> to be inspired to  and help you get involved, for the benefit of our community of , as well as the global community, and our planet. 
        </p>
          </div>
         </section> 
         </div>
    
    
<div id= "imgc3">
    <div id="Imgtxt2">
        <div id= "border3">
            <div id= "opacityforborder3">
            <h1 align="center" class= "moreinfo"> To find out more information </h1>
                <button class= "button1" onclick="location.href = 'default.asp';">Click Here</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
    
     <div id= "section3">
         <span id= "contacts">
         <h2> Contacts </h2>
         </span>
         <div id= "Mygmail">
         <h3> My Gmail<span id= "dots">......................................................</span>More References</h3></div>
       
         
         <div id= "stuff1">
         <button id= "button2" onclick="location.href = 'https://www.lipsum.com/feed/html';"></button>
             
             <span id= "refs">  <span id= "linktext">Here are some more links if you are looking to go more in depth into water conservation! </span><br> 
                 
                 
                  <span id="link01"><a href="https://saveourwater.com">https://saveourwater.com</a></span>
    <br>  
                 <span id= "link1"> <a href="https://www.farnellfamily.com/cfarnell/why/default.html">https://www.farnellfamily.com/cfarnell/why/default.html</a></span><br>
                 
           <span id= "link2"> <a href="https://learn.eartheasy.com/guides/45-ways-to-conserve-water-in-the-home-and-yard/">https://learn.eartheasy.com/guides/45-ways-to-conserve-water-in-the-home-and-yard/</a> </span><br>
                 
                 <span id= "link3"> <a href="https://www.constellation.com/energy-101/water-conservation-tips0.html">https://www.constellation.com/energy-101/water-conservation-tips0.html</a></span><br>
                 
             <span id= "link4"> <a href="https://www.lipsum.com/feed/html">https://www.lipsum.com/feed/html</a></span></span>
             </div>
         </div>
    
    
    <div id= "imgc4">
    <div id="Imgtxt3">
        <div id= "border4">
        
            <img id= "image1" src="wix3.png">
            <span id="byme">By All rights reserved</span>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
    

    
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your html class name "List" where as in css its "list". change "List" to "list" in html. please keep the class name in html and css same. or else they will not work.

```css
.list {
    background-color: #666;
    color: #111111;
    height: 105px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="List">
    
    </div>
    
<!--    in the above class name is "List". change it to "list" -->
   <div class="list">

   </div>
```